# GSI account linking was not found during simulation

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Thank you for submitting your Assistant app for review. Unfortunately, your app has been denied for the following:
1. If your Actions require account linking or login information, the credentials provided in your testing instructions must work as expected. At the moment, we are unable to successfully proceed with testing.
In this case, GSI account linking was not found during simulation.
can anyone can help me please ?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your action. Are you doing user authentication somehow?

Comment: @NickFelker
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', async (conv) => {

      const {
          payload
      } = conv.user.profile;
    
      
      if (payload) {
           conv.ask(`Bienvenue .`+" \n Que puis je faire pour vous?");
      } else {
          conv.ask(new SignIn());
      }
        
    
   
 


})

Comment: You're using Google Sign-in?

Comment: @NickFelker yes i add account linking google sign in https://ibb.co/qBWDTY2

Comment: Did you provide testing instructions? Does your action actually do sign-in at any point?

Comment: yes it does !
for testing instructions i just sent the account to them to sign in with for testing.